# Navigation bar, last li is not inline with the others and I cant use the last approx 50px of nav bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a navigation bar that runs accross the top of my website but for some reason the last 'li' (contact) is not aligned with the other buttons and there is some sort of padding after the last 'li' that I didnt code which is very strange. Any chance anyone could take a quick look please?

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">

                <nav>
                    <ul class="sf-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html"class="current">Home<em>start here</em></a></li>
                        <li><a href="History.html">History<em>our legacy</em></a></li>
                        <li><a href="index-2.html">Repertoire<em>our dances</em></a></li>
                        <li><a href="index-3.html">Members<em>our dancers</em></a></li>
                        <li><a href="index-4.html">Join us<em>come &amp; learn</em></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.html">contact<em>reach us</em></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    background:url(images/nav-bg.png) top center no-repeat;
    height:116px;   
    margin:0px 0 0px 0;
}
#page1 .menu {
    margin-top:-188px;
}
nav {
    padding:0px 0 0 0;
}

.sf-menu {
    margin:         0;
    padding:        0;
    list-style:     none;
    width:100%;
    background:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:50
}
.sf-menu li {
    float:left;
    font-size:1.3333em;
    line-height:1.2307em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 10px 0 0
}
.sf-menu .last {
    padding-right:0;
}

    .sf-menu li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        zoom:1;
        position:relative;
        z-index:20;
        color:#000;
        text-align:center;
        padding:50px 26px 33px 26px;
        font-family: 'Cantarell', arial, serif;
}
    .sf-menu li a em {
        color:#9f9f9f;
        font-size:0.5625em;
        line-height:1.2307em;
        display:block;
    }


.sf-menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    width: 185px;
    border:none;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
    background:#1c1c1c;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;

}

    .sf-menu li a:hover {
        background:url(images/nav-hover.png) left top repeat-x;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .sf-menu .current {
        border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
        position: relative;
        background:url(images/nav-current.gif) left top repeat-x;
    }
        .sf-menu li .current:hover {
            background:url(images/nav-current.gif) left top repeat-x;
            color:#000;
        }
            .sf-menu li .current:hover em {
                color:#9f9f9f;
            }
    .sf-menu li a:hover em {
        color:#fff;
    }


.sf-menu ul li {
    width:          100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
    visibility:     inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
```

Comment: [Looks fine in Chrome and Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/bNngg/). What browser?

Comment: Is this a horizontal alignment issue? Is meant to align with a background image?

Comment: it is yes but it has nothing to do with the background image. It's the text that doesn't line up. All of them line up beautifully but for some reason the last li (contact) does not line up with the others?

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset to make sure no browser styles are applied? Elements such as UL are core reasons why resets are used.

Comment: David, I have just checked the webpage in a different browser and it works fine so I think that may be the issue. I have no idea what a CSS reset is,could you please elaborate? thank you.

Comment: The question still stands which browser are you using? Even IE9/IE10/IE11 look fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the code sample you're posting there is no content after your floating elements, that might be an issue; clear floats after your menu container.

```css
.sf-menu:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear: both;
}
```

---

This selector currently doesn't match anything:

```css
.sf-menu ul {
  position:absolute;
  width: 185px;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
  background:#1c1c1c;
  border-radius:6px;
  -moz-border-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px;
}
```

Did you want to select `ul.sf-menu`?

---

You also might want to remove/modify the padding of the last item:

```css
.sf-menu li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.sf-menu li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```